# How to dynamically create variables and use them in anchor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple HTML page where I show the buttons, the buttons are added by the user, user can add multiple buttons. the buttons have anchors, which I need to pass variables.

So far I am doing it manually like this:

**The Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="ad.size" content="width='320',height='320" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <title>interactive Interactive Images</title>
</head>

<script>
    let buttons = [
          {
            buttonId: 103676,
            link: "ww.google.com",
          },
          {
            buttonId: 432549,
            link: "www.yahoo.com",
          },
        ];
    
        var clickTag1 = "www.google.com";
        var clickTag2 = "www.yahoo.com";
</script>

<body>
    <div class="conatiner">
        <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag1)">
            <div data-id="103676" class="button-simple">first points</div>
        </a>

        <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag12)">
            <div data-id="432549" class="button-simple">first points</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Because users can have multiple buttons I do not want to add the variables to the anchors manually as I do know.

How can create those variables clickTag1, clickTag2 clickTag3 ..... etc based on available buttons and pass them to anchors?

**Expected result**

For example, if we have an array of buttons like this

```
 let buttons = [
      {
        buttonId: 103676,
        link: "ww.google.com",
      },
      {
        buttonId: 432549,
        link: "www.yahoo.com",
      },
    ];
```

The final html should be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
     var clickTag1 = "www.google.com";
    var clickTag2 = "www.yahoo.com";
</script>
<body>
  <div class="conatiner">
    <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag1)">
      <div data-id="103676" class="button-simple">first points</div>
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag12)">
      <div data-id="432549" class="button-simple">first points</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have a button wrapped in a link (`<a>` tag)? How are user buttons/links stored? Sounds like you may want to use an Object. Also, you don't seem to be using jQuery here.

Comment: Anchors can't be children of buttons and buttons can't be children of anchors. Both are invalid HTML

Comment: @mykaf is for google ads , https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7046799?hl=en

Comment: What, exactly, is for Google ads?

Comment: @j08691 I know that but I am following Google documentation on creating  banners for Google ads as you can see example here https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7046799?hl=en  , I mean inside anchor can be anyting div, image etc

Comment: @mykaf those ads you see  when you visit websites etc , banners, yes is for Google ads

Comment: I know what a google ad is, but you haven't explained why you have to do it like this for google ads. Or answered any of my questions. Why go through the trouble of a `window.open()` with the link when you can simply update the `href` of the anchor?

Comment: @mykaf that is what Google documentation says,   I am just following the google docs

Comment: Does your html work if you change `var clickTag1 = "www.google.com"` to `window.clickTag1 = "www.google.com"`?

Comment: do you intentionally misspell `class="conatiner"`?

Comment: Ref for anchor re: content cannot be interactive like links buttons etc: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-a-element.html

Answer (score 4):

I have removed the button because like people said you cant have buttons inside of anchor tags. I have reused your buttons variable. Looped through it and created a link for each button. You can modify this to be a button that calls a function that opens a page if you want to use buttons instead of anchors.

The script has also moved to the bottom so that the container exists before executing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="ad.size" content="width='320',height='320" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  <title>interactive Interactive Images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <script>
  const buttons = [{
      buttonId: 103676,
      link: "ww.google.com",
    },
    {
      buttonId: 432549,
      link: "www.yahoo.com",
    },
  ];
  const createButton = ({
    buttonId,
    link
  }) => {
    const a = document.createElement("a")
    a.textContent = "first points";
    a.href = link;
    a.setAttribute('data-id', buttonId);
    a.setAttribute('target', "_blank"); // open in new tab behvaiour
    return a;
  }
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0]; // P.S. you spelt container wrong in your id!
  buttons.forEach(button => container.appendChild(createButton(button)));
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks does not need to be a button can be anything you want :

Comment: and the final result should be something like this <a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag1)">
        <div data-id="103676" class="button-simple">first points</div>
      </a>  as google wants

Comment: @TheDeadMan No it should not. Google doesn't want that. [You should use a proper `href` on your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/134957/1048572), as this answer suggests. And really even if you went the route of calling `window.open`, there is no reason to use a global `window.clickTag1` variable as the argument. Just `window.open('www.google.com')` or better `window.open(buttons[0].link)` would work just fine.

Comment: @bergi actually the documentation discourages you from using normal links saying that such links might not be tracked. You need to read the linked articles which also describes how "exit links" need to be defined. There are even worse examples over there, using <div onclick=> instead of <a href>.

Comment: @SalmanA What do you mean by "exit links" and them being "tracked"? Links should be hyperlinks that are accessible to screenreaders or search engines in the first place.

Comment: @bergi OP has added a link in the comments (not in the post which is bad). This html will be displayed as a Google ad, placed inside bunch of iframes. The documentation specifically says don't use normal links.

Comment: @SalmanA Oh I see now. That definitely should have been in the question, it's changing the requirements completely. I'd even recommend asking a new question specifically about dynamically creating ad manager links.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want it like that, but to make a dynamic variable, you can use this syntax:

```
window[`clickTag${buttonCounter}`] = link;
```

Example:

```js
let buttons = [{
    buttonId: 103676,
    link: "ww.google.com",
  },
  {
    buttonId: 432549,
    link: "www.yahoo.com",
  },
];

var clickTag1 = "www.google.com";
var clickTag2 = "www.yahoo.com";

const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
const add = document.getElementById('add');

add.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const buttonId = document.getElementById('id');
  const link = document.getElementById('link');

  buttons.push({
    buttonId: buttonId.value,
    link: link.value
  });

  window[`clickTag${buttons.length}`] = link.value; // add this

  const newA = document.createElement('a');
  newA.setAttribute('href', `javascript:void(window.open(clickTag${buttons.length}))`);
  const newAChild = document.createElement('div');
  newAChild.setAttribute('data-id', id.value);
  newAChild.setAttribute('class', 'button-simple');
  newAChild.innerText = `${buttons.length} points`;
  newA.appendChild(newAChild);
  container.appendChild(newA);
});
```

```html
<input id="id" type="text" placeholder="id" />
<br>
<input id="link" type="text" placeholder="link" />
<br>
<button id="add">Add</button>

<div class="container">
  <a href="javascript:void(window.open(clickTag1))">
    <div data-id="103676" class="button-simple">first points</div>
  </a>

  <a href="javascript:void(window.open(clickTag2))">
    <div data-id="432549" class="button-simple">second points</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

That should generate something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open(clickTag3))">
  <div data-id="23535" class="button-simple">
    3 points
  </div>
</a>
```

You can verify that the new clickTags are added as new variables from the console:

[image]

Comment: Putting a block level element (div) inside of an inline element (a) is invalid.

Comment: Also javascript:void on an <a> doesn’t “smell” right. Just make the wrapped div have a click event handler.

Comment: @ScottMarcus none of these make any sense, I know, but I'm just combining what OP wants and also the docs that OP mentioned https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7046799?hl=en

Comment: @ScottMarcus `<a href="#"><div>Link</div></a>` - is valid code

Comment: Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-a-element.html scroll down to the HTML5 content notes i.e. no interactive content like buttons or other anchros/links

Comment: yeah, but that's not the point of my answer, both the fact that `div` inside `a` and `javascript:void` inside `href` are not my idea, they're both from OP's code and that google admanager link

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is **"how to create multiple incremental variable"**. The option you can do is with using object of `window`:

```js
let length = 5;
for(let i=0; i < length; i++) {
  window[`clickTag${i+1}`] = 'This is clickTag'+ (i+1);
}
console.log(clickTag1);
console.log(clickTag2);
console.log(clickTag3);
console.log(clickTag4);
console.log(clickTag5);
```

This is a working example that match with your expected result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="ad.size" content="width='320',height='320" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" /> -->
    <title>interactive Interactive Images</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    let buttons = [
      {
        buttonId: 103676,
        link: "www.google.com",
      },
      {
        buttonId: 432549,
        link: "www.yahoo.com",
      },
      {
        buttonId: 132548,
        link: "www.outlook.com",
      },
      {
        buttonId: 686432,
        link: "www.bing.com",
      },
    ];

    let container = document.querySelector('.container');
    let inner = '';
    let varName = '';
    buttons.forEach((b,i) => {
      varName = `clickTag${i+1}`;
      window[varName] = b.link ;
      inner += `
        <a href="javascript:window.open(window.${varName})">
          <div data-id="${b.buttonId}" class="button-simple">first points</div>
        </a>
      `;
    });
    container.innerHTML = inner;
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your answer add anything new to the 9 existing answers?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, you need to generate exactly the global variables in `window`.
So here's what I would do if I were you:

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<script>
  const buttons = [
    {
      buttonId: 103676,
      link: 'www.google.com',
    },
    {
      buttonId: 432549,
      link: 'www.yahoo.com',
    },
  ];
  let html = '';
  const variables = buttons.map((el, index) => {
    const key = `clickTag${index + 1}`;
    window[key] = el.link;
    html += `
      <a
        href="#"
        onclick="
          window.open(window[${key}]);
          console.log('Variable: window.${key};', 'link: ${window[key]}')
      ">
        ${key}
      </a>
      <br>
    `;
  })
  document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have an object with all the details and iterate it. Create the required html and insert it to you container.

Object will look something like this.

```
var myTags = [{
        buttonId: 103676,
        link: "https://www.google.com",
        text: "First points"
      },
      {
        buttonId: 432549,
        link: "https://www.yahoo.com",
        text: "Second points"
      },
      {
        buttonId: 432550,
        link: "https://www.cnn.com",
        text: "<b>Third points</b>"
      },
    ];
```

Your loop should look something like this. I used `jQuery` as jQuery is tagged in the question.

```
$(function() {

      var html = "";
      $.each(myTags, function(key, value) {
        html = html + '<a href="javascript:window.open(`' + value.link + '`)"><div data-id="' + value.link + '" class="button-simple">' + value.text + '</div></a>';
      });

      $("#ads-container").html(html);

    });
```

You HTML will look like this. Container html will be populated from the script.

```
  <body>
    <div class="conatiner" id="ads-container">

    </div>
  </body>
```

Check the working demo here - https://jsfiddle.net/msabq0e2/1/

NB: adding fiddle example as StackOverflow is not allowing `window.open`

Note : I have used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in the code. If IE11 is among your target browser you need to replace it.

Answer (score -1):

As per your problem this is work for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#addanchor').click(function(){
    
   let buttons = [
     {
       buttonId: 103676,
       link: "https://www.google.com",
       label:"first point"
     },
     {
       buttonId: 432549,
       link: "https://www.yahoo.com",
       label:"Second point"
     },

   ];
   
    $.each(buttons, function (index, button) {
      let dynamicVariableName = "clickTag" + (index +1);
      window[dynamicVariableName] = button.link;
      let data_id = button.buttonId;
      let label = button.label;
      $('.container').append('<a href="javascript:window.open(window.'+dynamicVariableName+')"><div data-id="'+data_id+'" class="button-simple">'+label+'</div></a>');
    });
 });
});
</script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="ad.size" content="width='320',height='320" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  <title>interactive Interactive Images</title>
</head>

<body>
<button id="addanchor">ADD</button>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why so much complexity?
It's just easy. Just use js+html.
No external libraries or other extra stuff.

```html
<div class="conatiner">

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
  
let buttons = [
      {
        buttonId: 103676,
        link: "www.google.com",
      },
      {
        buttonId: 432549,
        link: "www.yahoo.com",
      },
    ];



buttons.forEach(function(button){
  document.querySelector('.conatiner').innerHTML += `

    <a href="javascript:window.open('https://${button['link']}')">
      <div data-id="${button['buttonId']}" class="button-simple">first points</div>
    </a>

  `;
});


// One line as below, if you want.

buttons.forEach(function(button){document.querySelector('.conatiner').innerHTML += `<a href="javascript:window.open('https://${button['link']}')"><div data-id="${button['buttonId']}" class="button-simple">first points</div></a>`;});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can turn it into an element the normal way. Here a simple way you can cut and paste into your current page. This would have to go at the end of the page. If you placed it in a script file, it would have to be a different script file then your other script and you would have to mark this script with the attribute of defer so the persons browser knows the run it after all the DOM elements have loaded.

```
<script>
    elements.forEach((element)=>{
        var data-id= element.getAttribute("data-id");
        var link="";
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                if buttons[i].buttonId === data-id{
                link = buttons[i].link;
            }
        element.setAttribute("href", "javascript:window.open("+link+)")
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me realize the problem, what you need is to create multiple buttons depending on an object from this form :

```
[
  {
    buttonId : 1234,
    link: "stackoverflow.com"
  },
  ...
]
```

Now, you need to define how the actual data is gotten, for example, is it taken when the page loaded (constant data) ? or by local storage ? user input ? fetch API ? you need to define how the data is being taken.

then, you need to define how the data is being displayed, which I am going to write  a function that render the data, and you can customize the function as you want . Let's start :

I am not going to use the jQuery, but let's start making the main container of the buttons :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMainConatiner"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then we make the rendering function, passing the ID of the container element, and the data of the button :

```js
function render(containerID, buttonData) {
    //You can change it anytime
    document.getElementById(containerID).innerHTML = `
        <div>
            <button id="${buttonData.buttonId}">${buttonData.link}</button>
        </div>
    `
}
```

and finally, you can code this in the main javascript file :

```js
/*
Use this code to deal with the fetch API, this is a very simple code

fetch("url").then(function(response){ 
    if(response.ok) return response.json()
}).then(function(data) {
    ...
})
*/

var data = myObj ;
//Do the main script you want for the dealing with the data .
```